# A one line rhyme?

Tags: rhymes

The wiki defines a rhyme as:

> ...A rhyme is a repetition of similar sounds in two or more words, most often at the end of lines in poems and songs...

But if I have just 2 words in a statement that in my opinion rhymes, can I say that the one liner rhymes. If 'rhyme' is not the correct term, then what is the correct term for it.

The one liner is "Chef Ash".

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Obviously *chef* and *ash* don't rhyme, but if they *did*, they *would*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Can I not consider the 2 words as near rhymes? To me it just sounds similar enough to be considered at least near rhymes.

Comment: For the purposes of *rhyme*, "similar sounds" generally means "same/similar **vowels**". The fact that the **consonant** /ʃ/ occurs in *chef* and *ash* (or *wash* and *trash*, for example) wouldn't normally be described as a "rhyme".

Comment: Do not depend on wikis for definitions that apply to everything.

Comment: Possibly related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/130814/what-different-types-of-rhymes-are-used-here

Comment: _Chef Jeff_ would count as what you dub a "one-line rhyme",  but, for _Chef Ash_, I'd side with our King of Consonance, @FumbleFingers

Comment: @J.R.: Until reading your comment I'd never really registered that connection between ***consonants*** (non-vowels) and ***consonance*** (more likely than ***rhyme*** when the "sim,ilar sound" turns more on consonants than vowels).

Answer (score 1):

I'd describe this as an example of either [assonance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assonance) or [consonance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_consonance) - or simply as an internal rhyme.

Comment: It seems more like consonance than assonance – that would describe the /ʃ/ sound at the beginning and end of _Chef Ash_.